# C Insert Node At Beginning Of Linked List

Tags: c, list, insert, structure, element

I have a function like so which is supposed to insert a given node into a linked list in an ascending order by PID number.

If the PID number is the lowest in the array then it will naturally put the new element as the first in the list.

The problem is that it doesn't work as intended.. I use an `if()` statement to check if the count is 0 because if it is then the PID of my new element is no larger than the elements PID in index 0. Therefore, the new element must be inserted at index 0.

Right now my code inside the if does not properly prepend the element, and sometimes when I try different code I get a segmentation error.

***Note:*** I CAN NOT change any function parameters and must work with what I've been given for a struct.

```
struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *Next_PCB ;
    int PID ;
};

void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
    struct PCB *tmp1 = Head;
    if (Head->PID == 0) {
        Head->PID = Add->PID;
    } else {
        if (Head->Next_PCB == NULL) {
            Head->Next_PCB = Add;
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            while (Head != NULL) {
                if (Add->PID > Head->PID) {
                    if (Head->Next_PCB != NULL) {
                        Head = Head->Next_PCB;
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        Head->Next_PCB = Add;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (Add->PID == Head->PID) {
                    Add->Next_PCB = Head->Next_PCB;
                    Head->Next_PCB = Add;
                    break;
                } else if (Add->PID < Head->PID) {
                    if (Add->PID == 1 || Add->PID == 2) {
                        printf("found 1 or 2");
                        printf("count: %d", count);
                    }
                    int ct = 0;
                    while (tmp != NULL) {
                        if (ct == 0) {

                            /* ERROR!!!!!!!!*/

                            Add->Next_PCB = (*tmp1);
                            (*tmp1) = Add;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (ct == (count - 1)) {
                            Add->Next_PCB = Head;
                            tmp->Next_PCB = Add;
                            break;
                        }
                        tmp = tmp->Next_PCB;
                        ct++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("pid : %d\n", Add->PID);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't mark this as duplicate. I've looked at all answers given on these forums with no luck, as they do not seem to directly pertain to my issue. If it's any consolation, I've spent 6 hours working on this problem, so I would LOVE just a straight up example of how it's done because I'm a newbie and I seriously, seriously, just need to get this done. Please and thanks.

Comment: `void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)` : It is not possible to replace the head of the elements in this interface. So, you need to the first element in the dummy elements(Anchor node that is not intended contents of the holding).

Comment: Or you need to swap the contents like a sort.

Comment: note : `Add->Next_PCB = (*tmp1);` this be trying to put the real thing to the pointer. `(*tmp1) = Add;` this be trying to put  the pointer to the real thing.

Comment: See, I don't know what that means. This is what I was supplied and told not to change the function headers. Can you give me a working example?